# POJO class with File Reader

Tags: java

I'm beginner, I would like to ask on how to read text file through POJO class and call the method from file reader ? I have go through many links but still not find any best solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

How to use POJO class, File Reader and text file all together ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is unclear. You want to call a method _from_ the FileReader? Or do you want to call a method of the FileReader class?

Comment: I'm sorry for that, i want to call a method of the FileReader class :)

Comment: [These examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) look OK.

Comment: So what's stopping you from calling a method of the `FileReader` class? What is the question?

Comment: Thanks for that link, but i'm not sure whta to do with my POJO class. How can i link my POJO class with the text file or how can i link my POJO class with my file reader ? Because, i need to use all three  which are POJO class, text file and File Reader. Thanks

Comment: Actually I'm confius on how to use the POJO class with the file reader. @EJP

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question. Include the POJO class. Indent it by 4 spaces to get it in `code markdown`. Maybe then we'll be able to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the contents from the Text file like any character/complete content. you can Read from file using FileReader and store into POJO class variables and use anywhere within your Application.

```
public class YourPOJOClass {

private char firstChar;
private String address;

public void setFirstChar(char firstChar){
this.firstChar=firstChar;
}
public char getFirstChar(){
return firstChar;
}
public void setAddress(String address){
this.address=address;
}
public String getAddress(){
return address;
}

}

::::::::file.txt:::::::::

I Love India

::::::::file.txt:::::::::




public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args){

YourPOJOClass pojoClass=new YourPOJOClass();

File file=new File("C:\\file.txt");
FileReader reader=new FileReader(file);

char[] contents=new char[20];
reader.read(contents);  //Reding and Storing into contents char[]

    pojoClass.setFirstChar(contents[0]); //Reading the first character and setting to Pojo class variable 'firstChar'
    pojoClass.setAddress(String.valueOf(contents)); //Reading the first character and setting to Pojo class variable 'address'

System.out.println(pojoClass.getFirstChar()); //Output: I
System.out.println(pojoClass.getAddress()); // OutPut: I Love India

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.